# show only 100 result from a select

Tags: c#, sql-server

let say I want to show only 100 result from a sql query

```
string str="select * tableA where id > 56";
```

that give me 12,000 and I want to show only the first 100 of that query

thanks

Comment: If you're using a Linq technology the answer will be different (`result.Take(100)`).  Are you using pure SQL Server queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string str="select top 100 * tableA where id > 56";
```

Comment: You would tend to want an order by clause as well as you could not guarantee which 100 rows you got.

Answer (score 3):

```
select TOP 100 * tableA where id > 56
```

You can use `TOP` to specify number of rows to be returned from the result.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you just want 100 random records that have id > 56 you should also order your results.